# how to develop a web app with angularjs at client-side and flask at backend?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, web-applications, flask

I want to develop a web app with flask(python) at server side and angularjs(javascript) at client side. I checked out the /flask-angular-seed project on github but it is same as the /angular-seed project. It does not contain any support for flask framework. I am new to flask. How to make flask and angular work together as server-client? I know how to create a web service using flask, and also I went through angular tutorial. But I am confused how to make these two work together(like what http request should be called and how flask receives and responds to it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typical Angular workflow and project structure with python flask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522151/typical-angular-js-workflow-and-project-structure-with-python-flask)

Comment: Yes Rod. I have exactly the same question that you mentioned in your comment. But I am still unable to figure out the solution. I think I have to add one app.py file that will handle the requests from frontend. But I still am confused in silly things like why there is routing both in frontend (angularjs) and backend (flask)? Assume that I want to get one request from frontend, process it and send back the response (some json, e.g.), how would one achieve that? I am sorry but I am very new to web development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I do it is to have a single route for the interface (eg /) that will load up the main html template. That template then references the js for your angular app in the static folder.

Then I create routes for the various interaction points (in my case it's rest-y) that angular talks too. I use an angular module called restangular to make that easier / cleaner. My routes return everything in json that can then be directly used.

I also set up and extra route so that /blah/whatever will also route through to the main interface. I ignore the path and once the angular js has loaded, the router (in angular) will look at the path and map it to the correct interface route.

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
@app.route('/')
def admin(path=None):
    return render_template('angular_interface.html')
```

Basically - for the interface I get flask out of the way completely.

EDIT: Folder-wise you might have something like:

```
__init__.py
api
api/__init__.py
api/resources.py
api/views.py
static/interface/css/style.css
static/interface/js/app.js
static/interface/js/other_modules_etc.js
static/shared/js/angular.js
static/shared/js/restangular.js
templates/interface.html
```

In my `__init__.py` I have the routing structure described above (and the Flask app stuff).

My interface.html template looks like the following.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blah</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='interface/css/style.css') }}"/>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='shared/js/angular.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='shared/js/restangular.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='interface/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
  {% raw %}
  <div ng-app="blah" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="BlahCtrl" class="sidebar">
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endraw %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Aidan. Can you please show me your directory map (output of 'tree' on your app folder) too? So that it might help me to structure my web application. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated with a simplified outline of how I layout the structure. Let me know if you need any more guidance.

Comment: Hey Aidan. Thanks for the reply. Could you please give me your email id so that I can ask you my specific doubts in mail(I mean, if you are willing to help me there)? Thanks.

Comment: I'd be happy to try to help. Not sure if my email in my profile is viewable, if not it's my first and last name together at that google based email.